# What are advantages to adding methods to a class vs adding methods to a class's prototype?

Tags: javascript

When I write a javascript class, its usually like this:

```
var myClass = function(prop1, prop2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;

    this.method1 = function() {//blah}
    this.method2 = function() {//blahblah}
}
```

But most books/tutorials I've read describe writing classes like this:

```
var myClass = function(prop1, prop2) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
}
myClass.prototype.method1 = function() {//blah}
myClass.prototype.method2 = function() {//blahblah}
```

What is the difference between these two approaches? Is one better than the other?

Comment: That's not a class. There is no such thing in JS. While some libraries implement something that could reasonably called "class", your code is a far shot from that. It's just a different way to write `function (pro1, prop2) { return { prop1: prop1, ... }; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach, using the prototype, is much more efficient if you create a large number of objects, and especially if you have a large number of methods.

The first approach requires all of the method functions to be created every time you call `new myClass()`. When you use the prototype these functions only have to be created once.

There is one advantage to the first approach: you can use your constructor function as a closure, so its methods have access to local variables in the constructor.

As a side note, your constructor function name should begin with a capital letter to follow normal JavaScript conventions.

Answer (score 0):

What you implemented are just functions. They can be used as constructors for creating objects. When a constructor is invoked, a new object is created and it has its `Prototype` set to the constructor's prototype property, which means that it shares properties with constructor's prototype. In the first case `method1` and `method2` are properties of each object created using `myClass` constructor. If those methods are the same amongs all objects created that way, it is a kind of memory wasting. If you put those methods into constructor's prototype, no new copies of them will be created when constructor is invoked, but created objects would still have access to them using prototype chain. So it's generally for saving memory.